# How to get the value of option in select symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I entred a select section in my view with two options.
I want to get the value selected and then depending on the entred value, I'll get a 
specific action.
How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

For a form POSTed containing the input variable 'foo',

```
$foo = $request->request->get('foo');
```

Comment: or `$this->getRequest()->request->get('foo');` if you didn't pass the `Request` in to the Action declaration.